# unpivot 2 columns into one column

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

I have tables like this:

```
ID|ServiceName|ServiceCode|Age      |Gender|Number|TotalCost|Location
0 | service1  |  0000234  |under 12 | Male | 121  |1234     |loc1
```

I want to change the table like this:

```
ID|ServiceName|ServiceCode|Age      |Gender|Measure    |Value |Location
0 | service1  |  0000234  |under 12 | Male | Number    |121     |loc1
1 | service1  |  0000234  |under 12 | Male | TotalCost |1234    |loc1
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two SELECTs, one for each Measure.

> ```
> create table tbl2 (ID int identity, ServiceName varchar(100), ServiceCode varchar(100),
>                  Age varchar(100), Gender varchar(100), 
>                  Measure varchar(100), [Value] int, Location varchar(100));
> ```

> ```
> insert into tbl2 (ServiceName, ServiceCode, Age, Gender, Measure, Value, Location)
> select ServiceName, ServiceCode, Age, Gender, 'Number', [Number], location
> from tbl
> union
> select ServiceName, ServiceCode, Age, Gender, 'TotalCost', [TotalCost], location
> from tbl
> ```

> ```
> select * from tbl2;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | ServiceName | ServiceCode | Age      | Gender | Measure   | Value | Location
> -: | :---------- | :---------- | :------- | :----- | :-------- | ----: | :-------
>  1 | service1    | 0000234     | under 12 | Male   | Number    |   121 | loc1    
>  2 | service1    | 0000234     | under 12 | Male   | TotalCost |  1234 | loc1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b8d197bee797911fc1241d3d61ef966)*

Answer (score 0):

Without UNION:

```
insert into tbl2 (ServiceName, ServiceCode, Age, Gender, Measure, Value, Location)
    select ServiceName, ServiceCode, Age, Gender, 
    case x when 1 then 'Number' else 'TotalCost' end, 
    case x when 1 then [Number] else [TotalCost] end, location
    from tbl,(values(1),(2)) X(x);
```